# How can we know that our laptop model has capabiliy to protect against overcharging the battery, and is able to set preferences?

Tags: power-management, lenovo-laptop

How can I know that my laptop model has the ability to protect against overcharging the battery, and whether it has a menu to setup the preferences?

Example: [this is my model, Lenovo G40](http://shop.lenovo.com/ng/en/laptops/lenovo/g-series/g40/#tab-features)

I am confused about how to read the spec, how to check for this feature.

Comment: Every modern laptop has this protection.

Comment: I try to google but why the specs said Processor 
Up to Intel® Core™ i7 processor? My processor is just core i5. Is the model is wrong? Then how to check or test this feature is exist?
I try to charge when the baterry up to 97%, but the charge icon showing charging..

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the setting for my Lonovo G40 core i5

set conservation mode = on

at Lenovo setting...

like [this](http://www.improdia.com/tech-tips/lenovo-battery-conservation-windows-10/)

[image: Lenovo Settings]

[image: Conservation Mode]